unable to set run destination in xcode while they are donwloaded in my system
I'm using macOs sonoma 14.4.1 and xcode 15.3 simulator setup 17.4, and I'm using it for react native. I'm trying to implement fastlane to deploy my app to deploy my app to testflight. but as i running command fastlane beta, my app getting build for first few times but there i'm facing an issue of authentication when it run for uploading it to testflight. And after running for 2 to 3 times my destination got unset from the xcode and if i try to run command for installing my app on the phone or simmulator then I'm this  enter image description here while i have installed the platform on my system. and if I'm restarting my system then its getting resolved itself. please help to find me a solution
I Tried many ways to fix it

Try to use this code for Fastlane
It's working without any issues with me
IOS_APP_SPECIFIER = 'com.xyz'.freeze
AND_APP_SPECIFIER = 'com.xyz'.freeze

# Fastlane update
update_fastlane

###################### SETUP ######################
dir = File.expand_path('..', Dir.pwd).freeze

APP_VERSION_NAME = "6.2.2".freeze
XCODE_PROJECT_PATH = "ios/#{PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj".freeze
XCODE_WORKSPACE_PATH = "ios/#{PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace".freeze
RELEASE_SCHEME_NAME = "#{PROJECT_NAME}".freeze
BUILT_PRODUCTS_PATH = "#{dir}/build".freeze
BUILT_DSYM_IOS = "#{dir}/build/#{PROJECT_NAME}.app.dSYM.zip".freeze ##sdc.app.dSYM.zip

###################### BEFORE ALL ######################
before_all do

    print "### Yarn install..  \n"
    yarn(command: "install", package_path: "./package.json")

end

default_platform(:ios)

########################## iOS LANES ##########################
platform :ios do
    desc "Build and push build to TestFlight"
    lane :beta do

        cocoapods(
            podfile: 'ios/Podfile',
            use_bundle_exec: false,
            repo_update: true,
        )
        
        Dir.chdir("..") do
            # code here runs in the parent directory
            sh "if ! grep -q '#include <functional>' ./ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h;  then chmod 755 ./ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h && sed -i '' 's|#include <string>|#include <functional>\\n#include <string>|'  ./ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h; fi"
        end


        api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
            key_id: "KGY3AYRK6Q",
            issuer_id: "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
            key_filepath: "fastlane/AuthKey.p8",
            duration: 1200, 
            in_house: false 
        )

        increment_version_number(
            version_number: APP_VERSION_NAME,
            xcodeproj: XCODE_PROJECT_PATH,
        )

        nextVersion = latest_testflight_build_number(
            app_identifier: IOS_APP_SPECIFIER,
            version: APP_VERSION_NAME,
            api_key: api_key,
        ) + 1

        print "IOS Next Release is #{nextVersion} \n"

        increment_build_number(xcodeproj: XCODE_PROJECT_PATH, build_number: nextVersion)
        
        update_project_team(
            path: XCODE_PROJECT_PATH,
            teamid: TEAMID
        )

        build_app(
            workspace: XCODE_WORKSPACE_PATH,
            scheme: RELEASE_SCHEME_NAME,
            output_directory: BUILT_PRODUCTS_PATH,
            clean: true,
            silent: true,
            suppress_xcode_output: true,
            xcargs: ' -allowProvisioningUpdates '
        )

        changelog = changelog_from_git_commits(
            commits_count: 6,
            quiet: true,
            # merge_commit_filtering: "exclude_merges"
        )

        upload_to_testflight(
            skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
            wait_processing_timeout_duration: 1200,
            app_identifier: IOS_APP_SPECIFIER,
            changelog: changelog,
            api_key: api_key,
        )

    sentry_config = property_file_read(file: "./android/sentry.properties")

    notification(subtitle: "Finished Building IOS", message: "#{PROJECT_NAME} #{APP_VERSION_NAME}_#{nextVersion}")

    end
end

